# Python Flask API Multiple Request or load Performance Test

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

My IP is bind with 0.0.0.0.
I am trying to deploy and test an API on my live server. My API script is based on Python and Flask.
I tested my code and it is working fine for localhost but I get error on Server live IP Address after updating program to async:

> curl: (28) Failed to connect to '123.88.8.88' port 5010 after 129572 ms: Connection timed out

My API was also working for remote access through live IP without async.
Then I tried to test my API performance by JMeter where I sent 50 requests within 10 seconds. Every request ended up with no response. Meanwhile my API is working with Postman normal test.

Then I tried to add async await method in my code by thinking that might be my program responding too soon before response. After I updated my code with async and updated flask async, my API is working fine with local host and if I try test response in Postman is is not giving any response on live server, but if I test API using terminal "curl" then I get perfect localhost response but I get error on server live IP address:

> curl: (28) Failed to connect to '123.88.8.88' port 5010 after 129572 ms: Connection timed out

Comment: This sounds like a firewall issue, or something with the live IP. Such issues are rarely related to software, so I suggest trying to revert back to how things worked (before async). If you see the same timeouts, then the problem is likely not in software. However, if non-async does work with the live IP, it might suggest a software issue, in which case adding a minimal code snippet that reproduces the problem would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue 1**
API was not returning responses on load testing with multiple response in limited time. After testing on low level load testing and by tracing hardware performance manager, issue was due to my server's CPU and GPU limitation. On low level testing Normally CPU uses up to 300% processing power and when it goes too high it crashes program.

**Issue 2**
Port :5010 was not working as default port number is :5000. Using amazon web server you have to allow there ports  as well otherwise the ports only allowed on server will be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Did you opened the port 5010 in your enviroment? I suggest you to use an NGINX and make a reverse proxy entry to your application.

Something like that:

```
location /{
      proxy_pass http://localhost:5010/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Comment: yes, my Port is opened i tested it

Comment: Did you opened the 5010 port to the internet?